# Difference Between "@@" and "@" in Twitter Cards

Tags: twitter, seo, metadata, meta, twitter-card

When I was coding my meta tag and trying to figure out what other companies have implemented, I noticed some of them have `@@` instead of `@`. Does this make any difference?

```html
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@@https://twitter.com/company">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@@company">
```

I always implement with only one `@` sign.

I was wondering, could this actually have something to do with SEO strategy?

Comment: The [Twitter Card Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#attribution) only appears to encourage the use of a single `@` in the value. Who do you see using two? Have you tried [validating](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) their cards?

Comment: [Huge, Inc](http://www.hugeinc.com) for example is one. Yes the card get validated.

Comment: Do you see this often? It could very well be that the extra *@* is hard-coded in their template. For instance, `content="@${username}"` is often seen in code samples on GitHub, and if the actual `username` variable contains the *@* already, you'll end up showing two.

Comment: I seen it 2 more times, forgot where, but wouldn't this lower your SEO?

Comment: Whether it lowers your SEO or not, I don't know (I doubt it, however). But it wouldn't necessarily break Twitter Cards if Twitter is searching the value for a matching *@username* expression. As long as there is *at least one* at-sign, their search would succeed.

Comment: True, I was just little curious.

Comment: I think it's safe to say it is probably unintentional.

Answer (score 1):

*Update: "@ is sufficient. @@ at your own risk." - [Twitter Engineer](https://twitter.com/rchoi/status/682073301854728192)*

---

After a cursory browsing of the [Twitter Card documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#attribution), I see only examples of a single at-sign (@) preceding content. In my experience, no other official convention or pattern exists, or is encouraged by the documentation.

One likely explanation for the redundancy could be confusion in the template. Suppose the following exists in your source:

```html
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@<?= $username; ?>">
```

If the `$username` variable already consists of an at-sign, the resulting output will contain two. Twitter may have no issue with this, depending on how they search the value for usernames. If they look for nothing more than an at-sign, followed by a valid username, *@@jonathansampson* is valid.

[Searching GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=twitter%3Acard%20content%3D&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) also didn't yield examples of developers explicitly and unequivocally desiring to use @@, but instead a smattering of resources showing the above pattern; an at-sign followed by a variable (which could also contain its own at-sign).